SOLANA SNIPER BOT
hi i am building a solana sniper bot using typescript in node.js using the ES modules in visual studio code environment. Its not working.

its finding it difficult to compile the ts script
it is finding it difficult to read my wallet key in the .env file.
Below is one of the errors an now getting

bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
undefined:1
undefined
^
SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse ()
at Object. (C:\CODINGPROJECTS\ama_sniper_bot\dist\config.js:9:50)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at Object. (C:\CODINGPROJECTS\ama_sniper_bot\dist\connection.js:5:21)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
4. help. i am stuck. i can even send you the zip file to help me work on it

You would get better answers if you shared your code I think
